# Simplifying an inverse trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry

How can I express the following in its simplest form?

$$\sin^{-1}\left(x\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\right)$$

I tried writing $x=\cos2y$ but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: what do you exspect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting $x=\sin A$ along with $\sqrt{x}=\sin B$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Let $y=\arcsin x\implies -\dfrac\pi2\le y\le\dfrac\pi2\implies\cos y=+\sqrt{1-x^2}$

and $x=\sin y$